# HashMap in Java Not Working

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

This is currently my second day coding in Java, no worries though I am not new to coding. Anyhow, I am not use to not having dictionaries like Python has, which can store a `Key` and `Value`.

That is when I came upon Java HashMaps. Currently, I can not seem to get them to work, and I am unsure why. Here is the code I am using, but these seems to be raising errors:

```
 Map<String, String> visual = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then here is the error it is generating:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type Map is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String>
    - HashMap cannot be resolved to a type
```

I am even importing the Hash libraries:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

**So simply my question is, why is the HashMap not working? Thank you! :)**

---

*P.S. Here is my little piece of code:*

```
public Map areaTotal() {
    Map<String, String> visual = new HashMap<String, String>();
    return visual;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Sorry, I guess I did forget to include some other information.

- Using Eclipse
- Only other import is Math

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to diagnose the issue. What is the name of your class (hopefuly not Map or HashMap)?

Comment: Name of my class is `Room`.

Comment: Show all your imports,i guess you are not showing all of them

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What tool is giving this error (an IDE, or `javac`), and where is the `rt.jar` file that it's using located?

Comment: Nope, only other import is `Math`.

Comment: There updated my question a bit.

Comment: Try this:     java.util.Map<String, String> visual = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: Do you have your own class named `Map` in the same package as this code?

Comment: Right, what these comments are getting at is that it looks like some other Map or HashMap class in your project is conflicting with the java.util classes.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you @erickson . I am not sure how I could overlook something like that. Yes I have something else named `map`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have another `Map` class in the same package which is not generic - this should be removed or renamed to something else

Comment: How will it affect when there is no other import?

Comment: well would produce this error if it exists in the same package as the class

Comment: hmm makes sense...but you can put that assumption in your answer to make it more clear....And you can then recommend to do something like this: java.util.Map<String, String> visual = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse once .worked for me.